Web Audio API: Occasional Skipped Audio Chunks When Playing Real-Time Stream in VueJS App
I'm working on a VueJS web application that receives audio data through a WebSocket and plays it in real-time using the Web Audio API. The audio data is sent as base64-encoded chunks which I decode and append to a SourceBuffer in a MediaSource.
The problem I'm facing is that occasionally, when the duration of audio is shorter, the audio chunks are received but not played immediately. When the next set of audio chunks is received, the previously skipped audio starts playing, followed by the new audio chunks.
Here is the code I am using to set up the audio playback in my component:
initAudioSetup() {
      this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
      const audioElement = document.getElementById("audio");
      audioElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource);


      this.mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", () => {
        this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("audio/mpeg");


        let queue = [];
        let isUpdating = false;


        const processQueue = () => {
          if (queue.length > 0 && !isUpdating) {
            console.log("PROCESSING QUEUE");
            isUpdating = true;


            this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
          }
        };


        this.sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", () => {
          isUpdating = false;
          processQueue();
        });


        // Listen for new audio chunks
        window.addEventListener("newAudioChunk", (event) => {
          const chunk = event.detail;
          const binaryString = atob(chunk);
          const len = binaryString.length;
          const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          queue.push(bytes);
          processQueue();
        });
        window.addEventListener("endOfAudio", () => {
          console.log("end of audio");
         
          console.log(this.mediaSource.sourceBuffers);
        });
      });
      audioElement.play();
    }

Audio data is received through a WebSocket and dispatched as newAudioChunk events.
Each chunk is base64-decoded and converted to a Uint8Array before being appended to the SourceBuffer.Occasionally, received audio chunks are not played immediately. Instead, they play only after new chunks are received.What could be causing these audio chunks to be skipped initially and then played later?

Could it be because you only addEventListener() after 'sourceopen' event?

This question looks very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275369/audio-appended-to-mediasource-buffer-doesnt-play-immediately-100-of-the-time

@WofWca I am receiving the audio chunks through the event listener but it is not being played. it is similar to the question you have commented, unfortunately there is no mentioned solution for it

I would suggest looking at the buffered and readyState properties of the HTMLMediaElement. For playback to proceed, you need readyState === HAVE_FUTURE_DATA
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-have_future_data
